# Inserting String from xml into mysql works, but sometimes results in PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I make a request to Amazon mws API and receive order details as a xml/json which I then save into mysql database.

Most of the data will be saved without any problems, but for one item title I receive the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Shoes & Sandals (Black, Adult-M US (7~10)/ EU (39~43))', '0',
>   '0')' at line 2

The php code for the insert is as follows:

```
foreach ($allorders as $orders){

$orderiddetail = $orders->amazonorderid;
// SET Paramater for API request

require("amazonListOrderItems.php");


$quantityordered = $orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['QuantityOrdered'];
$quanityshipped = $orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['QuantityShipped'];
$title = $orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['Title'];
$sellersku = $orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['SellerSKU'];
$asin = $orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['ASIN'];


// INSERT
try {
      $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO order_details(amazonorderid, asin, sellersku, title, quantityordered, quantityshipped)
        VALUES ('$orderiddetail', '$asin', '$sellersku', '$title', '$quantityordered', '$quanityshipped')");
      $statement->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
       $result = "Double entry";
    } else {
echo $e;
break;
}
}
// INSERT  END

};
```

The text in the error message is from variable $title, $quantityordered, $quantityshipped.

Can you please tell me which characters causes the error? I'm using single quotes (') for the Insert, that's why I thought the forward slash (/) should be no problem?
After I've checked I found out the tilde (~) is a UTF8 character and should be no problem, too?

As I've said, the Insert will work for about 20 orders and then stop for this one order.

Comment: You need to escape your input. Best with prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you. I need to go back to study again then. I've never managed to get it to work with prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to change it to prepared statements like @juergen-d said.
Thank you very much. I had some errors about variables are not allowed to be NULL, that's why I've also set up some if variabel is NULL lines. Also the word "asin" seems to be a reserved word in php, so I've changed it to asins.

```
foreach ($allorders as $orders){

$orderiddetail = $orders->amazonorderid;
// SET Paramater for API request

require("amazonListOrderItems.php");


$quantityordered = (int)$orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['QuantityOrdered'];
$quanityshipped = (int)$orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['QuantityShipped'];
$title = $orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['Title'];
if($title === NULL){
  $title = "";
}
$sellersku = $orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['SellerSKU'];
if($sellersku === NULL){
  $sellersku = "";
}
$asins = $orders['ListOrderItemsResult']['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['ASIN'];
if($asins === NULL){
  $asins = "";
}

// INSERT
try {
      $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO order_details(amazonorderid, asins, sellersku, title, quantityordered, quantityshipped)
        VALUES (:orderiddetail, :asins, :sellersku, :title, :quantityordered, :quanityshipped)");
         $statement->bindValue(':orderiddetail', $orderiddetail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $statement->bindValue(':asins', $asins, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $statement->bindValue(':sellersku', $sellersku, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $statement->bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $statement->bindValue(':quantityordered', $quantityordered, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $statement->bindValue(':quanityshipped', $quanityshipped, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $statement->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
       $result = "Double entry";
    } else {
echo $e;
break;
}
}
// INSERT  END

};
// END of foreach
```